# jquery multiple select - how to be notified when an item selected, and know which item was selected

Tags: jquery

I have a "cities" multiple select list box that contains :

1 - First item is "All cities"

2 - Remaining items are the cities in a selected country

I am trying to implement the following behavior :

1 - When the first item ("all cities") is selected, unselect any other items (unselect any city items that are already selected)

2 - if any item except the first is selected (a city is selected), unselect the first item if it's selected (but don't unselect any other cities that are selected)

I have tried handling onChange - but I have no idea how to get which is the last item that was selected.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your markup and script, say in a jsFiddle or something. Without any code to start from, the best I can tell you is "add the correct events to the correct elements". Which is, all told, not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm assuming that by saying "multiple select list box" you mean `<select multiple>` element.

Then here we go...

The first behavior you mentioned don't need any action, because the default action from this kind of select is unselect all the options when you click another option without `CTRL (or CMD in Mac)` pressed.

And for the second, you must listen for changes in the `select` element, and then verify if the option `AllCities` is selected AND if there are another `options` selected with it.

So the code would me like...

You have the HTML:

```
<select id="cities" multiple>
    <option value="All" selected>All Cities</option>
    <option value="A">City A</option>
    <option value="B">City B</option>
    <option value="C">City C</option>
</select>
```

And the script that listen for changes and check if option `All` is selected AND if there are another options selected too:

```
$('#cities').on('change',function(){
    var it = $(this);
    if(it.val().indexOf("All") > -1 && it.val().length > 1){
        $('option[value="All"]',it).prop('selected',false);
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gE2kk/) to show its behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, however this does not behave quite correctly. This disallows you from selecting "All cities" after you have selected one or more individual cities. I would like it to allow selecting "All cities" and in doing that, unselect everything else.